# AWS Batch Operation - completion reports, no message

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I make batch operations in my lambda function on a huge number of csv files. I want to have the content of error/exception in my completion reports. I have only 5% of error files so lambda works fine, but it doesn't write errors in the report.

When I test my lambda on a file that leads to errors, I see that "ResultMessage" is the same as error or exception. I tried adding a string with exception to report but the last column is always Null.

Can you help me?

```py
    except ClientError as e:
        # If request timed out, mark as a temp failure
        # and S3 Batch Operations will make the task for retry. If
        # any other exceptions are received, mark as permanent failure.
        errorCode = e.response['Error']['Code']
        errorMessage = e.response['Error']['Message']
        if errorCode == 'RequestTimeout':
            resultCode = 'TemporaryFailure'
            resultString = 'Retry request to Amazon S3 due to timeout.'
        else:
            resultCode = 'PermanentFailure'
            resultString = '{}: {}'.format(errorCode, errorMessage)
    except Exception as e:
        # Catch all exceptions to permanently fail the task
        resultCode = 'PermanentFailure'
        resultString = 'Exception: {}'.format(e)
    finally:
        results.append({
            'taskId': taskId,
            'resultCode': resultCode,
            'ResultMessage': resultString
        })   
   
    return {
        'invocationSchemaVersion': invocationSchemaVersion,
        'invocationId': invocationId,
        'results': results
    }
```

Example rows of my report with failed csv

[image]

Comment: Please show us the try block as well - at least the AWS API calls you're making, without it it's hard to guess what the errors might occur, because we have no clue what data you're processing.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing obviously wrong with your code.

I checked the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-invoke-lambda.html):

> **Response and result codes**
>
> There are two levels of codes that S3 Batch Operations expect from Lambda functions. The first is the response code for the entire request, and the second is a per-task result code. The following table contains the response codes.
>
> | Response code | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | Succeeded | The task completed normally. If you requested a job completion report, the task's result string is included in the report. |
> | TemporaryFailure | The task suffered a temporary failure and will be redriven before the job completes. The result string is ignored. If this is the final redrive, the error message is included in the final report. |
> | PermanentFailure | The task suffered a permanent failure. If you requested a job-completion report, the task is marked as Failed and includes the error message string. |

Sounds to me like you'd need to look into the [Job Completion Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-examples-reports.html) to get more details.